# Error 127 - recipe for target failed - When compiling Google NaCl examples from Pepper 19?

Tags: makefile, google-nativeclient

When I run the make batch file in my Cygwin terminal I get the following output:

```
mparadis@A-082-MPARADI-0 ~/pepper_19/examples$ make  
make -C dlopen  
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/nacl_sdk/pepper_19/examples/dlopen' /cygdrive/c/nacl_sdk/pepper_19/toolchain/win_x86_glibc/bin/i686-nacl-g++ -o dlopen_x86_32.o -c
dlopen.cc -m32 -g -O0 -pthread -std=gnu++98 -Wno-long-long -Wall  
Makefile:92: recipe for target `dlopen_x86_32.o' failed  
make[1]: *** [dlopen_x86_32.o] Error 127  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/nacl_sdk/pepper_19/examples/dlopen'  
Makefile:33: recipe for target `dlopen_TARGET' failed  
make: *** [dlopen_TARGET] Error 2
```

It took some time to get Python properly set up because I needed the language interpreter package for it and was not aware I didn't have it already. My `env` variable for Python is correctly set to `C:\python27`. I get the same results when compiling my co-workers code which, I can compile fine on a Mac or Linux box. Unfortunately, I need to get this working in my Cygwin environment as well.

Anybody with any experience using google native client or know why this is happening please advise. I've been at this for so long I'm staring cross-eyed at the computer screen.

UPDATE:

If I insert the `--version` flag into the referenced command within the makefile, I receive the same error as above. However, if I type the command, as is, from the same working directory as the make file I get the following:

> mparadis@A-082-MPARADI-0 ~/pepper_19/examples/dlopen> $ /cygdrive/c/nacl_sdk/pepper_19/toolchain/win_x86_glibc/bin/i686-nacl-g++.exe -o dlopn_x86_32.o -c dlopen.cc -m32 -g -O0 -pthread -std=gnu++98 --version
>
> mparadis@A-082-MPARADI-0 ~/pepper_19/examples/dlopen $

In other words, it simply thinks for a split second, then returns to the prompt.

Comment: Building the examples works fine for me from a MSYS terminal. Does the executable `i686-nacl-g++` actually exist on that place, and what do you see when you invoke it like that with `--version` as argument?

Comment: I had no problems building this the first time I set it up but, for other reasons I needed to uninstall everything and have had this problem on my machine ever since (it does it on another machine i just tried setting it up on.

Comment: It is in that location and the proper version here's a screen dump:  
mparadis@A-082-MPARADI-0 ~/pepper_19/toolchain/win_x86_glibc/bin
  $ i686-pc-cygwin-g++ --version
  i686-pc-cygwin-g++ (GCC) 4.5.3
  Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

  I'm wondering if there's a Cygwin package I'm missing.

Comment: OK, but what happens if you exactly repeat the command `/cygdrive/c/nacl_sdk/pepper_19/toolchain/win_x86_glibc/bin/i686-nacl-g++ --version`? I think error 127 indicates that the executable is missing.

Comment: If I insert the --version flag into the referenced command within the makefile, I receive the same error as above. However, if I type the command, as is, from the same working directory as the make file I get the following:  

'code'mparadis@A-082-MPARADI-0 ~/pepper_19/examples/dlopen
$ /cygdrive/c/nacl_sdk/pepper_19/toolchain/win_x86_glibc/bin/i686-nacl-g++.exe -o dlopn_x86_32.o -c dlopen.cc -m32 -g -O0 -pthread -std=gnu++98 --version

mparadis@A-082-MPARADI-0 ~/pepper_19/examples/dlopen
$ ls
dlopen.cc  dlopen.html  eightball.cc  eightball.h  make.bat  Makefile'

Comment: Sorry, that last one was a mess, I couldn't figure out how to use the mini-Markdown formatting for code. In a nutshell what happens is, i type that in exactly as above and it does nothing other than go to a blank shell prompt '$'

However, if I type that full path with exe name and only use the version flag I get the version info.

Comment: Could you please add that information from your last comment as an update to the question, in a readable way?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Done, sorry about that.

Comment: Install Process explorer and look how many processes are started up. bin/i686-nacl-g++.exe is a redirector to real libexec/x86_64-nacl-g++.exe executable. It is important to know whether real executable starts up or not. You can also try to call libexec/x86_64-nacl-g++.exe directly but this must be done outside of cygwin (that is why this small redirector is needed).

Answer (score 0):

***[tl;dr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TL;DR):*** your **cygwin** may be **buggy** and give this return code ***to all batch file***. My does this. My cygwin version:

```
$ uname -srv
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.17(0.262/5/3) 2012-10-19 14:39
```

---

From your comment, I see something called "**make.bat**":

```
mparadis@A-082-MPARADI-0 ~/pepper_19/examples/dlopen
$ ls dlopen.cc dlopen.html eightball.cc eightball.h make.bat Makefile
```

You can test your cygwin with this little *bash* script, too..

```
#!/bin/bash
echo echo foo %errorlevel% bar >temp.bat
./temp.bat
if [ $? -eq 127 ]; then echo "bug"; fi
```

If your make recipe for that target uses `make.bat`, and you have this bug, then this cygwin bug is causing the Error 127